# ExtJS -- grid rowwidget plugin creating widgets on scroll

Tags: extjs

I have an ExtJS 6.5.1 app. I have a grid that uses the "rowwidget" plugin with a grid as the widget. If I scroll the parent grid all the way to the bottom then back to the top, it creates a duplicate widget for that row causing unexpected behavior.

[Here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2k7q&view/editor) is the fiddle.

Steps to reproduce:
 1) Expand any row 
 2) scroll parent grid all the way to the bottom
 3) scroll back to top

and you will notice the length of the widget component increasing meaning multiple instances are being created. After a while everything breaks and I get all sorts of errors.

Comment: Aparently, it has to do with the repeated records in the first grid. In your fiddle, just change the parent grid data to unique values, put a number before each name for example, and the strange behavior stops

Comment: it doesnt have to do with duplicate records but the number of records. You can check the latest fiddle I have added unique records and even replaced the plugin widget with a textfield and multiple instances are still created on scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I find the culprit, the grid is "bufferedRenderer: true" by default, set it to false

```
bufferedRenderer:false
```

otherwise it keeps erasing the widget when the row is out of view and when you scroll back it creates another one